# jgitflow-maven-plugin and GitHub Issue

Tags: java, maven, github, maven-3, jgitflow-maven-plugin

My Jenkins release job, which uses jgitflow-maven-plugin to release an Open Source project on GitHub, throws an exception though it used to work.

Maven goals:

```
jgitflow:release-start -e -X -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

jgitflow:release-finish -e -X -Dgpg.useagent=false -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Exception:

```
[DEBUG] (develop) committing all poms on branch 'develop'
[DEBUG] (develop) adding file pattern for poms commit: pom.xml

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.763 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-11T12:31:56+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/492M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-finish (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-finish failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-finish (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-finish failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-finish failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.AbstractGitFlowCommand.failedResult(AbstractGitFlowCommand.java:133)
    at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.AbstractGitFlowCommand.doPushIfNeeded(AbstractGitFlowCommand.java:104)
    at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.ReleaseFinishCommand.call(ReleaseFinishCommand.java:148)
    at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jgitflow.manager.DefaultFlowReleaseManager.finish(DefaultFlowReleaseManager.java:99)
    at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jgitflow.mojo.ReleaseFinishMojo.execute(ReleaseFinishMojo.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
```

What worked:

- a release branch has been created in the remote GitHub project
- the artifact with the released version number has been pushed to https://oss.sonatype.org/
- the local develop branch has been updated with the next development version

But no commit has been pushed to GitHub. The remote release branch does not have any new commits either.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.AbstractGitFlowCommand.failedResult(AbstractGitFlowCommand.java:133)
at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.AbstractGitFlowCommand.doPushIfNeeded(AbstractGitFlowCommand.java:104)
```

This looks to me as something went wrong when the plugin wanted to push the commits, but the error message got lost because of a NullPointerException in failedResult!?

Does anyone know what change on the GitHub infrastructure might cause this issue?

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-112-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT of the plugin provided a better error message:

```
Caused by: com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.exception.JGitFlowGitAPIException: error pushing to develop - status: REJECTED_OTHER_REASON - error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/develop.
error: At least one approved review is required by reviewers with write access.

        at com.atlassian.jgitflow.core.command.AbstractGitFlowCommand.doPushIfNeeded(AbstractGitFlowCommand.java:107)
```

I had to remove the "Include administrators" flag on the branch protection configuration in GitHub.

I filed an issue to make this version available: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-298